# How do I get Users from one database and save their Profile in another database using Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am building a REST API that uses 2 postgresql databases: db1 (default) and db2. I want to get users from db2 and create a profile for them to store in db1. So basically, db2 is used for read-only. I already set databases (added DATABASES in settings.py and run migrate), and set managed=False in the User model but the users do not appear when I enter the admin page (I added User model in admin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, django uses `default` database, to redeclare it in admin interface, use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface) instruction from docs.